# Differences between S3 and Google Cloud Storage preventing Chrome HTML5 audio from loading

Tags: html, google-chrome, http, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I have some HTML5 code that makes use of the HTML5 Audio "canplaythrough" event to detect when music is finished loading.

Here is the page when referring to the MP3 file hosted on Google Cloud Storage:
http://moovd-translated-production.storage.googleapis.com/294348a6-8dfa-4a11-961a-fb28c7d9fc45_480p.html'

When the "canplaythrough" event is fired, using the Buzz HTML5 audio library, a play button should appear.

What happens is that Chrome gets stuck in (pending) and does not proceed loading. Here is a screenshot of the Developer Tools Network tab, see the last line for the mp3 file:

[image: See last line]

The generated request in `curl` form is:

```
curl 'http://storage.googleapis.com/moovd-translated-production/uploads/music/mp3/6/emotive.mp3' -H 'Referer: http://moovd-translated-production.storage.googleapis.com/294348a6-8dfa-4a11-961a-fb28c7d9fc45_480p.html' -H 'Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36' -H 'Range: bytes=0-' --compressed
```

I changed this to show headers only `--head` and get from the shell:

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Expires: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 12:00:29 GMT
Date: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 11:00:29 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Last-Modified: Wed, 09 Apr 2014 14:22:58 GMT
ETag: "dfe1015fb2e479721cf7cea99c1aa9ac"
x-goog-generation: 1397053378181000
x-goog-metageneration: 3
x-goog-stored-content-encoding: identity
x-goog-stored-content-length: 3043484
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
x-goog-hash: crc32c=ZExbIQ==
x-goog-hash: md5=3+EBX7LkeXIc986pnBqprA==
x-goog-storage-class: STANDARD
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Range: bytes 0-3043483/3043484
Content-Length: 3043484
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 7 2014 11:59:06 (1396897146)
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
```

When the same content is hosted on AWS S3, it loads properly:
http://moovd-translated-production.storage.googleapis.com/a9e16b41-5b9d-4376-9f0e-5cda0ecd6c78_480p.html

It starts out as (pending) but continues loading.

Request and response:

```
curl 'http://moovd-translated-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/music/mp3/6/emotive.mp3' -H 'Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: http://moovd-translated-production.storage.googleapis.com/a9e16b41-5b9d-4376-9f0e-5cda0ecd6c78_480p.html' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Range: bytes=0-' --compressed

HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
x-amz-id-2: ULg38QGKIlEWaxbRwFzt0hvbm01Chw5ZsFelKrpXs2zPJlyoYZBFZ07d6hYikpiV
x-amz-request-id: D57F144132757325
Date: Sun, 13 Apr 2014 11:16:22 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 28 Nov 2013 01:53:22 GMT
ETag: "dfe1015fb2e479721cf7cea99c1aa9ac"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Range: bytes 0-3043483/3043484
Content-Type: audio/mp3
Content-Length: 3043484
Server: AmazonS3
```

Screen shot, the mp3 file is also on the last line:

[image]

This problem happens with Chrome but not in Safari or Firefox.

The second time I access the mp3 file hosted on Chrome, it loads correctly.

I'm not sure if it's related, but loading the mp3 file hosted on Chrome directly on the URL bar also got stuck in "Waiting for Cache" on the status bar. I could not find a pattern for this behaviour.

Comment: I just tried pasting "http://moovd-translated-production.storage.googleapis.com/294348a6-8dfa-4a11-961a-fb28c7d9fc45_480p.html" into my Chrome status bar and a video immediately showed up with music and such. The emotive.mp3 bit loaded just fine. I was using Chrome 34.0.1847.116.

Comment: Thanks for checking! Yes I couldn't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Could it be being blocked by some AdBlock setting or another plugin?